# Displaying degree symbol in popup template of ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, encoding

I am editing javascript code of ArcGIS API for JavaScript for online map.

the piece of code is here:

```
var lvEsriPopupT = new esri.dijit.PopupTemplate(
                   {  
                      "title": "Weather",
                      "outFields": "*",
                      "fieldInfos": [{
                         "fieldName": "Temperature",
                         "label": "Temperature  deg& C",
                         "visible": true}, 
                         ... ],
                      ...
                  });
```

The code works fine. the issue that I am trying to fix, is displaying the degree symbol inside double quotes.
anything I tried (° ℃ ℃) comes ups without being decoded to the actual symbol. I suspect it is because it is inside double quotes.

Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why Didn't you use directly the ° character ?

otherwise use js `String.fromCharCode` function to render char from It's ascii code (degree = 176 ) like bellow :

```
var lvEsriPopupT = new esri.dijit.PopupTemplate(
    {  
      "title": "Weather",
      "outFields": "*",
      "fieldInfos": [{
         "fieldName": "Temperature",
         "label": "Temperature "+String.fromCharCode(176)+"C",
         "visible": true}, 
         ... ],
       ...
    });
```

Comment: does it solve your issue ?

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked perfectly. I tried to use ° character but in my code editor (notepad ++) it would change to normal o.

Comment: Great :) , So please up and mark the answer as resolved ✓ (left the answer ) ( like in this image =>[image resolve post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T8umg.png) ) thank you .